# MCMC using GIBBS sampling: can different burn-in be used for different parameters?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I have run a stochastic volatility model with 4 parameters. I have used the Heidelberg and Welch convergence diagnostic. The result shows 3 out of 4 parameters have passed the stationary and half-width mean test but the 4th parameter failed the tests. I wanted to ask if I can use a different burn-in period for just the 4th parameter?

Comment: Just to understand your suggested strategy, how would you implement a different burn-in period just for the 4th parameter?

Comment: The Gibbs sampler is intended to converge to the stationary distribution for the entire parameter, hence it cannot converge for one set of parameters and not for another.

Comment: You can try and update the 4th parameter more often than the others (perhaps based e.g. relative autocorrelation times from previous runs). This might help if the problem is that you are not doing proper Gibbs sampling (e.g., you have a Metropolis step because you cannot properly sample from the 4th parameter). Do not stop sampling from the first three parameters -- it would be a disaster. Have a look at the approximate sampled posteriors so far and see what's the problem: is it highly correlated? Is it multimodal?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Xi'an's comment, your stationary distribution in four dimensions, and each sample drawn via Gibbs sampling is a four dimensional vector.

In fact, (unless you are using block Gibbs sampling in a particular way), each component of the Markov chain is **not** a Markov chain, and thus convergence cannot be assessed for each component separately. More formally,

Let $\pi(x)$ be the stationary distribution for the Markov chain $\{X_t\}_{t>0}$. Here is the state space is $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$. Then the draws are,
\begin{align*}
X_1 &= (X_{11}, X_{12}, X_{13}, X_{14}) \\
\vdots\\
X_n & = (X_{n1}, X_{n2}, X_{n3}, X_{n4}).
\end{align*}

Convergence is assessed on $X_1, X_2, \dots$ and **not** on any $i$th component $X_{1i}, X_{2i}, \dots$. Thus is the 4th component $X_{\cdot 4}$ has not converged to its marginal of $\pi(x)$, then that means that the whole Markov chain has not converged.

One way to address your more larger problem is to use a [Random Scan Gibbs Sampler](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~zhaoxia/publications/paper3_Yuzx.pdf) and setting the 4th component to be updated with larger probability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If $X_{j,t}$ denotes the $j$-th component of $X_{t}$ ($1 \leq j \leq 4$), can we still expect the sequence of empirical averages 

$$ \Big( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{j,k} \Big)_{n \geq 1}$$

to converge as $n \to +\infty$ ($j$ is fixed) even though the sequence $(X_{j,t})_{t > 0}$ is not a Markov chain ?

Comment: Yes, we can expect that because the vector $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$ converges as $n\to \infty$, and thus individual components also converge.